# Difference in Date between Oracle and Teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, date, calendar, teradata

I ran into a strange problem while calculating the difference between two dates in Oracle(11.2.0.3.0) and Teradata(13.10.07.15).
NLS_CALENDAR parameter in Oracle is set to GREGORIAN.

```
Oracle                                                              Teradata
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select trunc(sysdate) - date'1800-01-01' diff from dual;            select date - date'1800-01-01' diff;    

DIFF                                                                diff    
----------                                                          ----------- 
78224                                                               78224
```

No difference so far.

```
select trunc(sysdate) - date'1500-01-01' diff from dual;            select date - date'1500-01-01' diff;

DIFF                                                                diff
----------                                                          -----------
187788                                                              187797
```

Difference of 9 days.

```
select trunc(sysdate) - date'1000-01-01' diff from dual;            select date - date'1000-01-01' diff;

      DIFF                                                          diff
----------                                                          -----------
    370413                                                          370418
```

Difference of 5 days.

```
select trunc(sysdate) - date'0500-01-01' diff from dual;            select date - date'0500-01-01' diff;

      DIFF                                                          diff
----------                                                          -----------
    553038                                                          553039
```

Difference of 1 day.

```
select trunc(sysdate) - date'0001-01-01' diff from dual;            select date - date'0001-01-01' diff;

      DIFF                                                          diff
----------                                                          -----------
    735297                                                          735295
```

Difference of 2 days.

Does anyone know why this difference?

Answer (score 4):

It's simple, Oracle is wrong :-)

```
select
   date '1582-10-04'+1, 
   date '1582-10-05'+1, 
   date '1582-10-14'+1, 
   date '1582-10-15'+1 
from dual;

|             DATE'1582-10-04'+1 |             DATE'1582-10-05'+1 |             DATE'1582-10-14'+1 |             DATE'1582-10-15'+1 |
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| October, 15 1582 00:00:00+0000 | October, 16 1582 00:00:00+0000 | October, 25 1582 00:00:00+0000 | October, 16 1582 00:00:00+0000 |
```

For date differences Teradata uses a Standard SQL calendar implementation, which is a proleptic gregorian calendar, while Oracle uses a proleptic Julian calendar (even if NLS calls it GREGORIAN).

See the paper from Gulutzan/Pelzer: http://www.orafaq.com/papers/dates_o.doc

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't explain why the difference between the two sets queries varies wildly with different dates. Also, the above query gives me 4th, 5th, 14th and 15th Oct when run in 11g. Which version did you run this in?

Comment: 11g R2. Yes, it's strange, it's somehow based on the 11 days which were omitted when going from Julian to Gregorian calendar, but ask Oracle for the details, why and how they did it :-)

Comment: I just noticed, that I pasted the wrong query for the result, it didn't include the `+1`. Of course you were a bit confused, I was to, when i re-read my answer.